# store result of void method in array (invalid conversion)

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in c and I'm getting an issue that I am having a hard time fixing. When I try to store the result of a method in an array I'm getting an invalid conversion error in `nodes [i]= print_postorder;`

```
char nodes[]= "";
    int i;
    for(i=0; i< 7; i++){
        nodes [i]= print_postorder;
    }
    if(sizeof(nodes) > 0){
     printf("There are at least one node in the tree");
    }
```

But the print_postorder is a void method so I dont understand how this should be.

There other parts that should be relevant to the issue, the post_order method

```
    void print_postorder(node * tree)
    {
    if (tree)
      {
        print_postorder(tree->left);
        print_postorder(tree->right);
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
       }
    }
```

The complete program where the issue is happening:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct bin_tree {
    int data;
    struct bin_tree * right, * left;
};
typedef struct bin_tree node;

void insert(node ** tree, int val)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
    }

}

void print_preorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
        print_preorder(tree->left);
        print_preorder(tree->right);
    }

}

void print_inorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        print_inorder(tree->left);
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
        print_inorder(tree->right);
    }
}

void print_postorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        print_postorder(tree->left);
        print_postorder(tree->right);
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
    }
}

void deltree(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        deltree(tree->left);
        deltree(tree->right);
        free(tree);
    }
}

node* search(node ** tree, int val)
{
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->left), val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->right), val);
    }
    else if(val == (*tree)->data)
    {
        return *tree;
    }
}

int main()
{
    node *root;
    node *tmp;


    root = NULL;
    /* Inserting nodes into tree */
    insert(&root, 9);
    insert(&root, 4);
    insert(&root, 15);
    insert(&root, 6);
    insert(&root, 12);
    insert(&root, 17);
    insert(&root, 2);

    /* Printing nodes of tree */
    printf("Pre Order Display\n");
    print_preorder(root);

    printf("In Order Display\n");
    print_inorder(root);

    printf("Post Order Display\n");
    print_postorder(root);

    char nodes[]= "";
    int i;
    for(i=0; i< 7; i++){
        nodes[i]= print_postorder;
    }

    if(sizeof(nodes) > 0){
        printf("There are at least one node in the tree");
    }

    /* Search node into tree */
    tmp = search(&root, 4);
    if (tmp)
    {
        printf("Searched node=%d\n", tmp->data);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Data Not found in tree.\n");
    }

    /* Deleting all nodes of tree */
    deltree(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char nodes[]= "";` creates array of a *single* character, and initializes that single character to the string terminator.

Comment: As for your build error, how do you *call* a function?

Comment: C does not support _methods_. Only normal _functions_.

Comment: Lastly, since arrays have a fixed size the `sizeof` of an array will *always* be larger than zero.

Comment: `print_postorder` does not return anything. You cannot assign *nothing* to something.

Comment: `nodes [i]= print_postorder` attempts to make `nodes [i]` equal to _a function itself_ (!), not _its return value_, but `nodes` is defined as an array of `char`, not _functions with the only argument of type `node *` that return nothing_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function with a return type of `void` means that it returns nothing.  So it doesn't make sense to assign the result (i.e. nothing) to any variable.

Even if it did return a value, you're not actually calling the function:

```
nodes[i]= print_postorder;
```

Without the parenthesis after the function name, the expression is actually the *address* of the function, not the result of calling the function.

What it looks like you want is for `print_postorder` to return the total number of nodes in the tree.  To do this, change the return type to `int` and return either the sum of the left and right subtrees plus 1, or 0 if the subtree is empty:

```
int print_postorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree) {
        int left = print_postorder(tree->left);
        int right = print_postorder(tree->right);
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
        return left + right + 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then to check the number of nodes, get rid of `node` and the loop and just call the function once.

```
printf("Post Order Display\n");
int node_count = print_postorder(root);

if(node_count > 0){
    printf("There is at least one node in the tree");
}
```